# Array values comparisong returning false

Tags: php, arrays, comparison

I have the following comparison:

```
if($panoraComparacion['center']==$updatedPanorama['center']){
        //Do stuff
}
```

Now the values of the 'center' array are as follows:

```
$panoramaComparacion['center']
latitude = -33.83306935448361
longitude = 150.435259765625

$updatedPanorama['center']
latitude = -33.83306935448361
longitude = 150.435259765625
```

They are the same, however the comparison is returning always false... Why is this? In php the  == will return true if all of the index and values of the array are the same right?. I'm sorry if this is a silly question, but I'm starting to learn php. Thanks a lot.

Comment: This isn't valid PHP code. Please paste exactly what's not working for you.

Comment: Have you used var_dump() on the two arrays just to make sure? Your code should work fine, it's probably a type error.

Comment: I think he's trying to compare two different arrays entirely. $panoramaComparacion['center'] is an array itself. Your best bet is to compare each value of the array independently, to confirm a true match.

Comment: Are those coordinates float values? Then you simply cannot rely on them being identical to begin with, arrays or not.

Comment: Please read the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php) before asking. First example on the link provided is for doing a comparison of arrays.

Comment: @Xavier his code is valid if they are not floats. See [documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.array.php)

Comment: @TusharDhoot Right, my mistake. Hopefully the person who asked the question can clarify it to be more helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$panoraComparacion`, really..? Try **`$panoramaComparacion`** instead:

```
var_dump($panoramaComparacion['center'] == $updatedPanorama['center']); // true
```